# Creating an "Invite Friends" Tab on Fan Page in iFrame

Tags: fbml

I've found many online tutorials about how to create an FBML tab on a fan page that lets fans invite their friends to the page, but all of these tutorials are outdated because it became impossible to create new FBML taps after March 11th. So I'm wondering now how to create an "invite friends" tab on my facebook fan page NOT using FBML. I know the "send" button has been cited, but it doesn't really work the same way. Is the "invite friends" application extinct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make facebook application, add it to your page and use Request Dialog in it's code
 http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/